# substring(IndexOf( ))

Tags: java, substring

I am a beginner in java programming. I want to get the first word from a text like "XX       X X,XX". But I got the answer like "XX  XX,". How to improve my code?
Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<String> optionCode = new ArrayList<String>();
while (File.hasNext()) {
    String code = File.nextLine();
    String code1= null;

    if(code.contains(" ")) {
        code1 = code.substring(0, code.indexOf(" "));
    }
    else {
        code1 = code;
    }

    optionCode.add(code1);
}
```

input txt :

```
LD      F0, 0(R1)
```

output:

```
LD            
F0
```

0(R1)

Here is the output I want:

```
LD
```

Comment: Can you show an actual output please.

Comment: if you're getting an empty string, the problem probably is [1] that your line is not "XX XX"  but " XX XX" or [2] you're printing the wrong thing. Notice that neither of these two parts are present in your code snippet, so actually there's no way for us to help you

Comment: , = \n in your example?????

Comment: your updated question now makes no sense.

Comment: I understand.I apologize for my mistake. I add some more comments now.Hope you can understand my problem

Comment: cool, my answer should work for you then

Comment: I bet those are `LD{tab}F0,{space}0`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler looks even worse than that - see the comments on my answer

Answer (score 1):

The above code looks OK and should work assuming that the blanks here are simply a space.

Alternatively you could try

```
String [] arr = code.split("\\s+");   // split on any whitespace
// of course test that arr has length before doing this
optionCode.add(arr[0]);
```

Comment: When I run your code.The output is "LD(enter)F0(enter)0(R1)(enter)". what I need is just"LD". @Java1

Comment: what do you mean by (enter)? is this having embedded \13 or something?

Comment: I mean the "Enter" on the keyboard. I can not use "Enter" in comment.

Comment: so where did the {enter} come from?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstand. I just edit my question. I mean the {enter} in the output.

Comment: so if you only want the first line change the `while` to an `if`

Answer (score 0):

All of this

```
String code1= null;

if(code.contains(" ")) {
    code1 = code.substring(0, code.indexOf(" "));
}
else {
    code1 = code;
}
```

Can be reduced to

```
int spaceIdx = code.indexOf(" ");
String code1 = ((spaceIdx == -1) ? code.substring(0, spaceIdx) : code);
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you mean.Just do it with below code:

```
ArrayList<String> optionCode = new ArrayList<String>();
while (File.hasNext()) {
    String code = File.nextLine();
    String[] arr = code.split("[^a-zA-Z]");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++){
        optionCode.add(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I do not follow the"[^a-zA-Z]" part. Could you please explain it to me @sunhang

Comment: The [^a-zA-Z] part is the regular expression,means to split the String by the non-character.I think the arr[0] is what you what.Hope it's useful for you.@user3375421